# Help understanding Texture2D multi-sampling semantics: Why do we need sample index AND location?

Tags: rasterizer, hlsl, antialiasing, unity, post-processing

Looking at the windows HLSL documentation for Texture2DMS.Load found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/texture2dms-load

can someone help me better understand different use cases for this? Specifically, I do not understand why you would need to specify BOTH the sample index and the location? Shouldn't those two pieces of information always be matched together? Why would you ever specify a sample index and simultaneously designate a location that is NOT that samples location???

I am new to learning how MSAA is fully implemented in the graphics pipeline. This load method here makes me lack confidence in my understanding so far. It seems to me that this method would automatically match the sample index with the sample location.

Or does the location simply refer to the pixel, rather than a position inside the pixel?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, location = the texel location and sample index specifies which sample index at that location. So if you have a 7x5 samplecount = 16 texture then location is 0 to 6 in x, 0 to 4 in y. At each location there are 16 samples, each with their own value.